ReactReader epub js - open table of content on load
ReactReader epub js - open toc on load (toc is table of content, a small button) which should be open upon page loading.
Checking npm guide, it only has option to show or hide toc.
Expecting a way to call the onclick event on button, but since it has no better selector, looking for a parameter option in epub js/ react reade module if there is any.

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
